# Botão para editar tags na lista de tags está empurrando o conteúdo para baixo

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tags, design

Na página de tags, quando colocamos o mouse sobre a tag aparece um link para editar a tag. O problema é que este link está empurrando o conteúdo para baixo.

[image: tags]

O mesmo acontece com outras tags, até mesmo tags que não tem uma descrição.

O mesmo ocorre no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1034&tab=popular).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213794/147423

Answer (score 2):

O problema que vejo é que ao traduzirmos para Português, o texto fica bem maior do que a sua versão original em Inglês.

Deveríamos simplificar as coisas de forma a reduzir a quantidade de informação aplicada num simples contador.

#### Alterar texto

Onde se lê "respondidas esta semana" sugeria ficar apenas "esta semana".

#### Texto incoerente

Por outro lado estamos a passar informação errada, "19 respondidas esta semana" não é a informação que estamos a receber do sistema, estamos a receber do sistema "19 colocadas esta semana". O link que vamos clicar pesquisa por perguntas e não por respostas:

```
http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&days=7
```

Como se pode verificar, o link aponta para "questions" colocadas nos últimos 7 dias.

---

## Resultado final:

[image: Simulação do resultado final]

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que uma solução seria mover este link, que não cabe abaixo da tag, para cima.

[image: editar tag no topo]

Acredito funcionar para ambos sites.